# Uncaught ReferenceError: show value is not defined(Only for mobile device)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, mobile

Hi I had implemented the code in which on adding to cart the item gets add and also one popup gets open which shows cart item.
On desktop it is working well but on mobile device it is not working.
For mobile device it is shoeing error as

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: showvalue is not defined
```

Here is my below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function showvalue(value, product) {

    $('#<%= lblproduct1.ClientID %>').text(product);
    $('#<%= lblVessel.ClientID %>').text(value);
    $('.cart_popup').show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.cart_popup').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 5000);
    return false;
}
function Showprogress() {               
    $('#<%= Progress.ClientID %>').show();      
 }
```

Html side on .ascx page

```
<asp:Button ID="AddToBasketButton" OnClientClick="Showprogress()" runat="server" OnClick="AddToBasketButton_Click" EnableViewState="false" ValidationGroup="AddToBasket" Text="Add to Cart" />
```

My .cs side code (Passing total and productquantity)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(UpdatePanel), UniqueID, "showvalue('" + Total + "','" + productquantity + "');", true);
```

I am facing issue for mobile device only.
On clicking button my page get refresh and popup is not getting open

Comment: I'm not familar with asp.net, but in jquery mobile for example you have "click" and "tap" as separate events, could something like this be the problem?

Comment: i didn't see any code which calls your function `showvalue()`

Comment: @Anant I am calling that from .cs code

Comment: @Gunnar for deskstop it is working fine and what you mean by tap?

Comment: Touch event, see here: https://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/ (or should "onClientClick" also work for touch events? Don't know, just a guess...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had remove jquery popup and made use of Ajax Modal popup.
The popup was opening fine as I was calling it from .cs side but to hide it automatically after 5 second it was not working in that case I had used below code.

```
<asp:Button ID="AddToBasketButton"  OnClientClick="Showprogress();" runat="server" OnClick="_Click" Text="button" />//button click and onclient click 
//Below div is only showing processing image :-)
<div id="Progress" runat="server" style="display: none;">
<img src="../images/spinner.gif" />
</div>
```

My script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { hide_pop(); });

function Showprogress() {       
    $('#<%= Progress.ClientID %>').show();
    hide_pop();
    return false;
}
function hide_pop() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.popup_cart_main').fadeOut('slow');//Popup Panel class
        $('.modalBackground').fadeOut('slow');//Background blacklayout Class
    }, 5000);       
    return false;
}
```

Modalpopup

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDummy" runat="server" ></asp:LinkButton>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BehaviorID="mpe" runat="server"
PopupControlID="pnlPopup" TargetControlID="lnkDummy" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="popup_cart_main" Style="display: none">
<div class="cart_popup" >               
      Solved         
        </div>
 </asp:Panel>
```

**This code is working in all browser and all mobile including iphone & Android**

I also think(According to actual question) that in case if I had not removed jquery popup and only placed below code my popup had been started working in mobile too

```
 $(document).ready(function () { showvalue (); });// based on actual question
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your script is rendered before calling RegisterClientScriptBlock. HTML parsing is linear.

Comment: If the script is not initialized properly than why should it works on desktop?

Comment: I am not sure if the render/build order is the same on mobile. The error states that the method definition cannot be found.
try this: alert(showvalue);

Answer (score 0):

- Did you miss to copy the  closing tag or you just didn't do it on code too?

It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function showvalue(value, product) {

    $('#<%= lblproduct1.ClientID %>').text(product);
    $('#<%= lblVessel.ClientID %>').text(value);
    $('.cart_popup').show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.cart_popup').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 5000);
    return false;
}
function Showprogress() {               
    $('#<%= Progress.ClientID %>').show();      
 }
</script>
```

- Try another approach:

In javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var jName = '<%=cName()%>'</script>
```

In c#:

```
protected string cName() {
    return "examplevarcontent";
}
```